# Need a batch script to grep a pattern and set in a variable

Tags: batch-file

As I am trying to grep a pattern from a file and then need to store in a variable using batch script. Below code i am using but its not working as expected:

```
for /f %%A in (grep "USI" %1/%CNID%.log | awk '{print substr($17,5,9)}') do set "var=%%A"
```

Comment: Could you show us some sample data from the file you're trying to grep?

Comment: Is Perl an option?  It does install and work on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Changed quotes and removed the non needed `grep` command

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
    awk "/USI/{print substr($17,5,9)}" "%1\%CNID%.log"
') do set "var=%%A"
```

Or, in cases where the `grep` is really necessary, you will need to also escape the pipe

```dos
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
    grep "USI" "%1\%CNID%.log" 
    ^| awk "{print substr($17,5,9)}"
') do set "var=%%A"
```

Comment: Thanks it works for me .. But can we use the substring in batch script . ex. I have search for a pattern that starts with some char and then it will grep next 10 character after that search.

Comment: @saurabh, sorry, i don't see clear what you are trying to do and comments are very limited. Could you start a new question and include more information on input data and expected output?